# Почему при инициализации библиотеки выскакивает ошибка в питоне?

Tags: python

Пишу импорты:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import messagebox 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
```

На что получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\Desktop\project.py", line 3, in <module>
    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  
File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 246, in <module>
    _check_versions()
  
File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 240, in _check_versions
    module = importlib.import_module(modname)
  

File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  
File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\kiwisolver\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._cext import (

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _cext: Не найден указанный модуль.
```

Как пофиксить?
UPD: При попытке uninstall matplotlib вылезает ошибка:

```
  Successfully uninstalled matplotlib-3.7.1
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 110, in run
    uninstall_pathset.commit()
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 424, in commit
    self._moved_paths.commit()
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 277, in commit
    save_dir.cleanup()
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 173, in cleanup
    rmtree(self._path)
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 328, in wrapped_f
    return self(f, *args, **kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 408, in __call__
    do = self.iter(retry_state=retry_state)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 364, in iter
    raise retry_exc.reraise()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 197, in reraise
    raise self.last_attempt.result()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\concurrent\futures\_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\tenacity\__init__.py", line 411, in __call__
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 129, in rmtree
    shutil.rmtree(dir, ignore_errors=ignore_errors, onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 759, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 622, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\shutil.py", line 620, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Отказано в доступе: 'C:\\Users\\vladragone.DESKTOP-S7C34G6\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\~atplotlib.libs\\msvcp140-e78ebc24b6ffa690be9375aacad743a7.dll'
```

Comment: Модули установлены с помощью pip?

Comment: Конечно, перепробовал и удаление, и скачивание заново, и полную переустановку - все тщетно
В один момент скачивание отпал интернет и библия норм не докачалась, но вроде потом скачал полностью и все, да и после этого делал полное удаление - мимо

Comment: Судя по последнему стеку ошибки, у вас Python3.11. В новых версиях очень часто бывают проблемы с установкой библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

Решение друг прислал, мне помогло:

```
pip install msvc-runtime
```